# How to make Div and Image flow inline in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt

There is following code in UiBinder

```
<div class="{style.flowInline}">
   <div class="{style.flowInline}" ui:field="text1Div" />
   <g:Image ui:field="image1" addStyleNames="{res.css.flowInline}" />
   <div class="{style.flowInline}" ui:field="text2Div" />
   <g:Image ui:field="image2" addStyleNames="{res.css.flowInline}" />
</div>
```

in Css

```
.flowInline
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This is the requirement. I want the **text1, image1, text2, image2**, flow in the same line.

```
text1Div.setInnerSafeHtml(SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("Please:<BR/> Click"));
text2Div.setInnerSafeHtml(SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("and<BR/> Click"));
```

It should show the result:

```
Please:
Click [image1] and
Click [image2]
```

But somehow it didn't work

If I don't use `Div` in UiBinder

```
<div>
   Please: <BR/>
   Click <g:Image ui:field="image1" /> and <BR/>
   Click <g:Image ui:field="image2" />
</div>
```

Then it work fine

So, how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to add float: left; to the style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Just threw this together but use float instead, it works very well. The style to clear the float will clear the float from the previous elements. You can also simply use clear:left. 
I prefer float to display:inline-block. I just typed this so there may be some mistakes but I think will get the idea.

```
<style>

.left {
  float: left;
}
</style>

<div>
   <label> Please: </label> <br />
   <div>
      <label style="float:left">Click</label>
      <g:Image ui:field="image1" addStyleNames="{style.left}" />
      <label class="{style.left}">and</label>
      <br style="clear:both" />
      <label style="float:left">Click</label>
      <g:Image ui:field="image2" addStyleNames="{style.left}" />
   </div>
   <br style="clear:both" />
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't tested ur solution, but i found other which does not use many csss: <div class=" {style.flowInline}"><span ui:field="text1span /><:Image ...><span ui:field="text2span /><:Image ...></div> & it work as i expected, but thax you anyway

Comment: I could have made it much simpler with a single style on the parent div but I was hoping that it would be more explanatory by breaking it out.